# Django - CreateView passing the created objects id to another CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

I've been trying to pass the values of a newly created object to the next CreateView so that a new child model can be created.

This is what happens:

1. User creates the Parent model through a CreateView
2. If the form is valid the success_url redirects to the CreateView of another Child model. The child model in order to be created, needs the id of the Parent Model (ForeignKey relationship).
3. Once the Child Model is created redirect to a completed page.

Below I have an example of my code.

```
class AddParentModelView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = ParentModel
    template_name = "dashboard/add_parent_model.html"
    form_class = ParentModelForm
    success_url = '/REDIRECT_TO_CHILD_MODEL/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        # I Also tried sessions: 
        # self.request.session['parent_id'] = form.instance.id
        # But they return None:
        # print(self.request.session["venue_id"])
        return super().form_valid(form)


class AddChildModelView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = ChildModel
    template_name = "dashboard/add_child_model.html"
    form_class = ChildModelForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'
```

What's the proper way to approach this? If possible, please explain your solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `get_success_url()` on AddParentModelView to return the child URL including the ID of the parent.

For example, if AddChildModelView has a URL like:

```
path('/<int:parent_id>/add_child', AddChildModelView.as_view(), name='add-child')
```

then define the method like:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('add-child', kwargs={'parent_id': self.object.id})
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Roseman! I've edited your answer to include the kwargs={}.